# Custom keymapping via udev/hwdb.d is not working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, udev

**Background**: I got the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 and several keys are not working at all under Ubuntu such as the F1-F10 keys. I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS running on my machine.

**My solution**:
I created the file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-keyboard-local.hwdb` and set up come custom rules:

```
keyboard:usb:v045ep00db*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_0x1008ff27=pageup
 KEYBOARD_KEY_0x1008ff26=pagedown
 KEYBOARD_KEY_0xff6a=F1
 KEYBOARD_KEY_0x1008ff6b=F5
```

I got the hex code through `xev`. For instance, for the key which should be the <kbd>F1</kbd> key, `xev` returns

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0xa2, subw 0x0, time 1746028, (12,-12), root:(61,40),
    state 0x10, keycode 146 (keysym 0xff6a, Help), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

After changing the file, I ran `udevadm hwdb --update` and `udevadm trigger` and, additionally, restarted my laptop.

**Issue**: The corresponding functionality is not assigned to the respective keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- That one from `xev` is the key symbol `keysym`, here the idea:

  /keyboard/ → `scancode` → /input driver/ → `keycode` → /X server XKB/ → `keysym`

  `man xev` says: **xev** - print contents of **X** events
- So, what you are looking for is the early hardware data from keyboard which is the `scancode`. It can be found using `evtest`

  `man evtest` **evtest** - Input device event monitor and query tool

  1. Install it

     ```
     sudo apt-get install evtest
     ```
  2. Run

     ```
     sudo evtest
     ```

     Output

     ```
     Event: time 1435906588.943349, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 3b
     Event: time 1435906588.943349, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 59 (KEY_F1), value 1
     ```

     Scancode is `3b`

Answer (score 0):

I got an external keyboard working in Ubuntu 20.04 using the information from https://www.foell.org/justin/remapping-keyboard-keys-in-ubuntu-with-udev-evdev/

1. use `sudo evtest` to find the info about your keyboard, like:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x5 vendor 0x5ac product 0x24f version 0x11b
Input device name: "Keychron K6 Keyboard"
```

2. use `sudo evemu-describe` to find the properties of the keyboard, including the leading zeros. In the output you can find something like:

```
# Properties:
N: Keychron K6 Keyboard
I: 0005 05ac 024f 011b
```

3. create the .hwdb file like you did but **include all the leading 000**, and **put any hexadecimal symbols in uppercase** like:

```
# Input device ID: bus 0x5 vendor 0x5ac product 0x24f version 0x11b
# evdev:input:b<bus_id>v<vendor_id>p<product_id>e<version_id>-<modalias>
evdev:input:b0005v05ACp024F*
```

4. you don't have to reboot your system, just do:

```
$ sudo systemd-hwdb update
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

5. you can check if your keyboard has been mapped correctly using `$ udevadm info /dev/input/event20` (replace event20 with the event for your keyboard)

Comment: Please be a little careful with posting exact copy and paste answers throughout Ask Ubuntu. Answers should be carefully tailored to exactly fit the question being asked.