# Fake key code for remapped keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, remapping

I have remapped my caps lock to backspace.

*/etc/default/keyboard*

```
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="altgr-intl"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBOPTIONS="caps:backspace"
```

This works pretty great, except that it doesn’t work for some specific tools. I used `xev` to find out what’s going on.

Backspace pressed

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x159, subw 0x0, time 1028211, (335,635), root:(452,749),
    state 0x10, keycode 22 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (08) "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (08) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x159, subw 0x0, time 1028272, (335,635), root:(452,749),
    state 0x10, keycode 22 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (08) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Caps lock pressed

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x159, subw 0x0, time 859789, (391,558), root:(508,672),
    state 0x10, keycode 66 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 22
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (08) "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (08) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x159, subw 0x0, time 859875, (391,558), root:(508,672),
    state 0x10, keycode 66 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 22
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (08) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I also tried it in the browser using

```js
addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  console.log(event.keyCode, event.key, event.code)
})
```

This logs the following when I press backspace and caps lock

```js
8 "Backspace" "Backspace"
8 "Backspace" "CapsLock"
```

So basically my caps lock is remapped to backspace, but it only works if tools and websites use proper checks. I don’s want to file a bug report for every tool or website I ever use that implements this incorrectly.

Is it possible to map caps lock in such a way that it fully emulates a backspace instead of acting like a remapped caps lock?

Comment: Can you give an example of a "tool" where it doesn't work? Do you  really mean backspace? Your xev output says "keycode 36 ... Return".

Comment: At least for Virtualbox and Visual Studio Code (Although there is a workaround), although I recall having this issue with other tools before. Also I made a mistake when copying xev output. I updated the question with correct output.

Comment: I guess the problem is that some applications determine keys by key code (e.g. 66 for CapsLock) and some by key symbol (e.g. 0xff08=BackSpace). You only changed the symbol, but the keycode is still 66 (backspace would be 22). In order to really emulate a backspace when pressing capslock, one has to change the scancode->keycode mapping in udev. I tried that in the past but didn't succeed. I'll give it a try again but hopefully someone comes up with an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, let's see how a key press is processed (taken from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/643883/354663)):

/keyboard/ → `scancode` → /input driver/ → `keycode` → /X server XKB/ → `keysym`

The `scancode` is a device specific code that is bound to a specific key and can differ between different vendors/products. `keycode` and `keysym` are propagated to applications. The `keycode` serves as an abstraction layer as it is device agnostic and locale agnostic. The same `keycode` can produce different `keysym`s, depending on the locale and the state of modifier keys. That is the reason why some applications only look for the `keycode`, especially when dealing with keyboard shortcuts.

So our goal is to map the `scancode` of your CapsLock key to the `keycode` of the BackSpace key. Applications will then see the same `keycode` and `keysym` regardless whether you press BackSpace or CapsLock.

This mapping is done by [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) using the **h**ard**w**are**d**ata**b**ase file (hwdb.bin) which is compiled from .hwdb files in both `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/` and `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/`.

---

## How to change `scancode`->`keycode` mapping

### Gather required information

First you have to determine the `bustype`, `vendor`, `product` and `version` of your input device (keyboard), as well as the `scancode` of the key you want to remap and the `key code identifier` you want to map it to.

Run `evtest` (you may have to install it first) and identify your keyboard in the list of devices. On keyboards with additional keys like Play/Pause, WWW, etc. these keys are often exposed as a different input device. If you don't get any output when pressing a key, hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and try a different device. Once you have identified your keyboard, remember the first column (`/dev/input/eventX`) and press the key you want to remap. The value after `(MSC_SCAN)` is the `scancode`. On my keyboard:

```
$ evtest
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Power Button
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  G19 Gaming Keyboard
/dev/input/event3:  G19 Gaming Keyboard
...
Select the device event number [0-18]:2
...
Event: time 1522111203.117945, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1522111220.778787, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN),value 70039
Event: time 1522111220.778787, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE), value 1
```

... the `scancode` is **70039**.

Now run the following command, where `eventX` is the one you chose before:

```
$ grep "" /sys/class/input/eventX/device/id/*
```

The output for my keyboard is

```
/sys/class/input/event2/device/id/bustype:0003
/sys/class/input/event2/device/id/product:c228
/sys/class/input/event2/device/id/vendor:046d
/sys/class/input/event2/device/id/version:0110
```

To get the `key code identifier`, either use the output of `evtest` or look at the *Keys and buttons* section in `/usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h` for a complete list. The identifier is the part after `KEY_` converted to lowercase, e.g. `KEY_BACKSPACE` becomes **backspace**.

### Configure udev

Take a look at `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/`. We will create a text file in **`/etc/udev/hwdb.d/`** with a filename beginning with a number greater than the file corresponding to our device type. For a keyboard, this can be any number greater than 60, while for a pointing stick it should be greater than 70. For example `65-keyboard-custom.hwdb`.
Use your favorite text editor, but keep in mind that you have to start it as `root`, e.g.

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/udev/hwdb.d/65-keyboard-custom.hwdb
```

Add the following content

```
evdev:input:b[bustype]v[vendor]p[product]e[version]*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_[scancode]=[key code identifier]
```

...where

- [bustype], [vendor], [product] and [version] have exactly 4 characters (pad with zeros if needed) and letters need to be **uppercase**
- [scancode] does not need padding but letters have to be **lowercase**
- the `evdev:...` line has **no preceding space**
- the `KEYBOARD_KEY...` line has **exactly one preceding space**

In my example, the file looks like this:

```
evdev:input:b0003v046DpC228e0110*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70039=backspace   # map CapsLock to BackSpace
```

The first line will be matched to your device. You can specify additional `evdev:` lines and you can use more than one wildcard (`*`) to match additional devices, but keep in mind that scancodes are device specific. You can also add more than one scancode mapping. Have a look at `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` for inspiration. A more detailed and up-to-date version of that file can be found in the [online repository](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb).

### Apply new configuration

Compile the new configuration to the hardware database:

```
$ sudo systemd-hwdb update
```

If you want to apply the changes immediately, inform udev:

```
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

Please note that configuration values can only be added or changed while the system is running. If you remove a configuration (e.g. scancode mapping), you have to reboot for the changes to take effect.

Remember to also revert the remapping you did before (using `/etc/default/keyboard`), because that will still be applied to all  keyboards.

Comment: I get the following value from `udevadm info /dev/input/eventX` `LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=11/1/1:isa0060/serio0`. Since this doesn’t match the format you described, I replaced the product id with a wildcard. This is probably not a good idea, but I can’t seem to undo this. (This may be a problem for future self.) Anyway, it works! Thanks!

Comment: Why does your output not match the format I described? bus is 11, vendor 1, product 1.  Seems to be a generic PS/2 keyboard. You can also look at the beginning of `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` where these match strings are explained further.

Comment: @Remco Haszing thank you for your feedback, I found a more user friendly way to obtain these values. I also added information about removing scancode mappings (only takes effect after reboot), I hope (for your future self) that was the problem you encountered.

Comment: Such a niche question has such a informative, well-written answer, almost makes me wanna cry and smoke a cigarette at the same time

Comment: nice explanation and guide details, make perfect sense to . but it doesn't work on my Ubuntu 20.04 and apple keyboard  
```
cat /etc/udev/hwdb.d/65-keyboard-custom.hwdb
evdev:input:b0005v004cp0267e0066*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c00b8=delete  # map EJECT to Delete
```

Comment: @Bo Chen try `evdev:input:b0005v004Cp0267e0066*` (i.e. with an uppercase "C")

Comment: @danzel you are my hero!! absolute HERO!!

Comment: "almost makes me wanna cry and smoke a cigarette at the same time "  -- feel the same way

Comment: Great answer! I found my new keyboard generates two scan codes for my lense key: `^@Event: time 1671265710.038740, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e3
Event: time 1671265710.038740, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 0
Event: time 1671265710.038740, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7002c
Event: time 1671265710.038740, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 57 (KEY_SPACE), value 0
Event: time 1671265710.038740, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------` so what can I do in this case (mapping two scan codes into one key code)?

Comment: @MaciekLeks I suspect that the scancodes are the same as for the individual space and meta keys. If that is the case, you're unfortunately out of luck. Your keyboard produces a series of key events when pressing that lense key that is indistinguishable from pressing the individual keys. For the input driver, there is no lense key. You can try to bind <meta>+<space> as a shortcut instead, but I'd suggest you ask a new question for that.

Comment: @danzel, yep the same key codes as for regular space and meta. The only way is to use key codes mapping in my case. I agree. Thanks.