# Automatically get screen shots

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, screenshot

After logging in to my Ubuntu 16.04 system, it automatically captures multiple  screenshots before the system hangs. How may I troubleshoot this effectively?

Comment: execute `cat /var/log/syslog` in a terminal directly after startup. It should give you a detailed overview. You can post the relevant lines of the startup here. Also, try to boot into a non-graphical mode. [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/310978/starting-ubuntu-without-the-gui)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gnome-screenshot taking shots randomly, also affecting Google Sheets](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053236/gnome-screenshot-taking-shots-randomly-also-affecting-google-sheets)

Comment: Please replace your keyboard; the PrtScr key may be stuck. Make sure, if you have a PS/2 style (round) keyboard connector, to turn off the PC before changing the keyboard; USB keyboards can be hot plugged, but PS/2 devices should not, in order to prevent the risk of circuit damage.