# Remapping gaming mouse buttons to key combinations

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, keyboard-layout, workspaces

I have Razer Deathadder Elite gaming mouse. I wanted to remap its two side buttons so that I would be able to [switch between workspaces](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-switch.html.en). I have seen this: [Remapping mouse buttons to keyboard keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145057/remapping-mouse-buttons-to-keyboard-keys), but could not figure out how to map the buttons to key combinations (i.e. Ctrl+Alt+Up and Ctrl+Alt+Down).

**Update**

Looked at this: [How to bind mouse buttons to keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9048/how-to-bind-mouse-buttons-to-keys?rq=1)
Tried adding the code below to `.xbindkeysrc`:

```
# Ctrl+Alt+Down press
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key Alt_L' 'key Down'"
    b:8

# Ctrl+Alt+Down release
"xte 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup Alt_L' 'keyup Down'"
    b:8 + Release

# Ctrl+Alt+Up press
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key Alt_L' 'key Up'"
    b:9

# Ctrl+Alt+Up release
"xte 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup Alt_L' 'keyup Up'"
    b:9 + Release
```

Still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, might this help you then? https://askubuntu.com/questions/9048/how-to-bind-mouse-buttons-to-keys?rq=1

Comment: @Sadaharu Wakisaka, still can't understant how to map Ctrl+Alt+Up and Ctrl+Alt+Down. Tried `"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key Alt_L' 'key Down'"`, still can't get it to work.

Comment: Check `xte` is installed or not. Restart service `killall xbindkeys ; xbindkeys`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact question for nearly the same exact purpose recently; figured it out:

```bash
# Ctrl + Alt + Down on Mouse8
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Down' 'keyup Alt_L' 'keyup Control_L'"
    b:8

# Ctrl + Alt + Up on Mouse9
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Up' 'keyup Alt_L' 'keyup Control_L'"
    b:9
```

I still couldn't figure out (just like you) why I couldn't "keyup" the three keys on a button release, but holding down the two modifiers, keying the arrow, then releasing the two modifiers worked out much better.

Just a note in your question, you were not holding down the Alt and Down/Up keys like you seemed to try (you used "key" instead of "keydown" on the press calls). Even then, the single-line press-release was the only way I got it to work.