# Remapping Keyboard Keys to mouse buttons on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse, remapping

I would like to use keyboard buttons for left and right mouse clicks. I found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145057/remapping-mouse-buttons-to-keyboard-keys/1145638) that describes remapping mouse buttons to keyboard keys. Can I use this method 'in reverse' to map keyboard keys to mouse buttons? E.g. F1 key = left click, F2 key = right click. I'd like the remap to apply on startup.

Comment: This might be helpful to you https://askubuntu.com/questions/9048/how-to-bind-mouse-buttons-to-keys

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `xdotool` if you run Xorg. `ydotool` will also work on Wayland.

For example, to simulate a mouseclick with the left button:

```
xdotool click 1 # left click
```

or

```
ydotool click left
```

Bind these commands to a shortcut key, e.g. using "Settings" - "Keyboard" for the default Ubuntu desktop. On `xorg`, you can also use hotkey daemons that are independent of the desktop, like `xbindkeys` or `sxhkd`. Note, however, that these may be unreliable if you switch keyboard layouts, or when the computer wakes from a suspended state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use the config below.

```
[ids]

*

[main]

f1 = leftmouse
f2 = middlemouse
f3 = rightmouse
```