# map Apple keyboard EJECT key to delete on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, remapping, eject, apple-keyboard

> followed this great instruction https://askubuntu.com/a/1019659/786192

but it didn't work for me. I then took a more aggressive approach and edited `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` directly by adding below

```
evdev:input:b0005v004cp0267*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c00b8=delete      # map EJECT to Delete
```

then systemd-hwdb update and udevadm trigger, still no luck ...

i've got the `bus`, `vender`, `product` all right, how come it's still not working? confused

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you wrote the hex codes in lowercase, for the vendor ID and for the keycode.

Try with:

```
evdev:input:b0005v004Cp0267*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_C00B8=delete      # map EJECT to Delete
```

and then:

```bsh
sudo systemd-hwdb update
sudo udevadm trigger
```

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 21

Comment: For me, it worked like a charm on Ubuntu 21.10.